# Could maths.SE use an appeals committee?

Tags: discussion, moderators

I spent several years as the arbiter for the [Croydon Chess Club](http://www.croydonchess.com/).  In the event that an arbiter's decision was disputed, the decision could be appealed.  If a decision were to be appealed:

- The decision is referred to the appeals committee, and they vote on a final ruling (no further appeals are possible).
- The arbiter plays no further role in the matter, and is obliged to accept the committee's decision.

This frees the arbiter to focus on the remainder of the tournament in progress.  It generally satisfies the players, since they can get around a bad decision (and we're all human).  It also prevents prolonged arguments.

Seeing the former moderators at this site swamped with tedious arguments makes me think an appeals committee might be useful here.

> **Question**: Could maths.SE use an appeals committee?

Comment: That is an interesting idea, but what is being appealed? Suspensions? Deletions? Closures? Downvotes? The fact that up until now only two people from this website bought me a beer (and I bought them one too, maybe we can count four - depending on how you look at it...)? The fact that I still haven't got that case of single malts that I was promised? And so on and so forth.

Comment: I'd suggest just moderator-enforced decisions.  So suspensions, deletions, closures, etc., that are the result of a diamond moderator using the diamond.

Comment: Deletions and closures already have an "appeals committee": users with high rep can vote to undelete and reopen.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are already two appeals committees in existence here: The community and the SE team.

Closures, edits and deletions can be brought before the community on meta, and the community has the power to reverse them.

For suspensions users can already appeal to the SE team by writing an email to `team@stackexchange.com` or using the contact form linked in the site footer. The SE team has the ability to override moderator decisions. The problem with any other appeal committee would be that suspensions very often involve private data that regular users cannot see, and that SE will not give to anyone not bound by the moderator agreement. The SE team also has additional powers that are sometimes used for trickier cases of sock puppeting or vote fraud which are not available to moderators.

Comment: Hmm... I guess you're right.  The meta is indeed a kind of appeals committee.

Comment: Out of curiosity: do you read *all* SE metas? (Also, there's an annoying typo in *existence*).

Comment: Aha, who is going to appeal on the fact that no one is sending me cases of single malt whisky? :\

Comment: The problem in case of writing to SE or moderators is that they will not even summarize the private data, including cases where the suspended users requested that it be made public.  This is precisely the sort of situation for which it is sensible to have an ombudsman, who is bound by a confidentiality agreement, but can see the data and represent the users.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, Old John seems to be quite the expert on whiskey. Perhaps you can work something out. Alright, it appears the extra letter 'e' is exclusively American spelling, I wondered about that.

Comment: @Will: Now now, don't give yourself the Americans too much credits. Whisky is Scottish and whiskey is Irish. E.g., Glenfiddich is a whisky and Jameson is a whiskey.

Comment: @Asaf, I guess I was hasty, I was reading Wikipedia and that was as much detail as I noticed.

Comment: @Asaf, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whisky#Names_and_spellings  agrees with you. They do not combine observations about spelling with dates, but Ireland had thisspelling before there was a U.S.A.

Comment: @xyz We already have users that are elected and represent the community: the moderators. All moderators can see the private information in suspension cases, so unless you distrust every single moderator and the SE community team there is already enough oversight for moderator decisions.

Comment: Mad Scientist, it is @zyx, in reverse order.

Comment: @MadScientist, unless the moderators act unanimously every time, that is not a protection.  According to the comment threads and answers, they do not.  Having an oversight and interface accountable solely to the users (an ombudsman) does not imply any great distrust for the moderators.  It only would show that the way the decisions *and information flow* are structured can be arranged in ways that are more transparent and correctible.

Comment: @zyx In cases of suspensions, *every* moderator on the site gets an inbox notification, and the whole SE community team is CCed on the mail. No moderator can silently suspend a user.

Comment: @MadScientist, sure.  But they don't have to all agree on the suspension, the duration or other aspects of the decision.

Comment: And then we'll need a higher appeal committee, because if you cannot trust the moderators, why would you trust the ombudsman? And surely we would need a *really* open way of electing this higher court, different to and better than the elections that pick mods and the ombudsman. And, to be honest, I would not trust that higher court *that* much either... The stakes are SO HIGH that we need such a structure!

Comment: @zyx If my fellow mods would perform a suspension that I find inappropriate, I would talk with them about it and discuss it. And maybe involve SE if we can't find a solution. An in complicated cases, the moderators often discuss the suspension before anyway.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, I don't think amount of trust in the moderators, or the height of the stakes, are even relevant concepts here.  It is possible to have full trust in the moderators and still think that a third type of entity bound by the same confidentiality agreements could help.  @ MadScientist, "inappropriate" is a high standard, you might be outvoted anyway, and there are reasons of information flow and trust by the community (something that is influenced by the structure and direction of the flows) that still exist no matter how nuanced the decision procedure is.

Comment: On a different note, while we are having a discussion here: thanks for the very large number of meta.MSE messages with explanations of lore from (m)SO, the other metas, and the network as a whole.  Those and 75064's postings are doing the heavy lifting on this meta and I'm pretty sure many other people have noticed.